# Idiomatic powershell translation of (cd $dir && someCommand)

Tags: powershell

I have a python script that spits out JSON I'd like to capture with `ConvertFrom-Json`. Unfortunately, this script requires that I cd to a different directory before I run it. What's the idiomatic powershell way to do this?

This works:

```
$q = powershell.exe -Command "cd some\other\dir; python JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json"
```

As does this:

```
$cwd=Get-Location
cd some\other\dir
$q=python JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json
cd "$cwd"
```

But changing the current working directory seems dicey to me - what if the python script outputs malformed JSON, will I be left in `some\other\dir` ?

In the unix shell scripting world, I'd obviously do something like

```
(cd some/other/dir && python JsonMaker.py) | commandThatUsesJson
```

or read the input in with `$(cd some/other/dir && python JsonMaker.py)`. However, in unix subshells are cheap. In powershell I see a noticeable delay to starting a subshell.

What's the approach long-time Powershell users take to something like this?

Comment: A few notes. 1) The current working directory (CWD) in Powershell is not necessarily in the file system. It could be in the registry, the cert store, etc. 2) CWD is not part of the scope, so you can't use an exit from a child scope to restore CWD 3) `cd fileSystemPath -UseTransaction` (at least in PS 3) doesn't work so you can't use a transaction to restore CWD. 4) So pushd/popd seem like the best alternative. 5) You can also run `ConvertFrom-Json` with `-ErrorAction stop` and put it in a try/finally to make sure you can recover from  a problem in converting JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python.exe JsonMaker.py` runs as a child process. Changes made to the current directory in a child process don't affect the parent. `ConvertFrom-Json` also doesn't affect the current directory. It converts a JSON string to an object representing the JSON data or throws a (non-terminating) error if the JSON string is malformed.

If you want to be on the safe side, run the conversion in a [`try`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) block and put the statement to return from the temporary working directory after that block:

```
try {
  $q = python JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json
} catch {
  # error handling (optional)
}

cd "$cwd"
```

or in a `finally` clause:

```
try {
  $q = python JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json
} catch {
  # error handling (optional)
} finally {
  cd "$cwd"
}
```

As others have already mentioned, I'd use [`Push-Location`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849855.aspx) and [`Pop-Location`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849842.aspx) (or their aliases `pushd` and `popd`) as a simpler way of changing to a different working directory and returning to the original directory. The cmdlets work similar to the Unix shell commands `pushd` and `popd`.

I'd also recommend adding the extension to the executable name (to avoid unintentionally running different executable files with the same basename (e.g. `python.cmd` or `python.com`) and using the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`). Running the command in a new `powershell.exe` process is not necessary, and would also return just a string representation of the object created from the JSON string instead of the object itself, which is probably not what you want.

---

Modified code:

```
Push-Location 'D:\some\other\dir'

try {
  $q = & python.exe JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json
} catch {
  # error handling (optional)
} finally {
  Pop-Location
}
```

or like this if you want to conditionally run the python script only if changing the directory was successful (thus fully emulating the behavior of `&&`):

```
try {
  Push-Location 'D:\some\other\dir' -ErrorAction Stop
  $q = & python.exe JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json
} catch {
  # error handling (optional)
} finally {
  Pop-Location
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use pushd/popd:

```
pushd some\other\dir
$q=python JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks fine to me. Unless `ConvertFrom-Json` throws a terminating exception (which I don't think it will), the script will continue and your `cd $cwd` line would reutnr you back.

You coulod also use `Push-/Pop-Location`, but it's basically just a "pretty" way of doing what you already have. Ex.

```
#Save location
Push-Location

#Script
Set-Location some\other\dir
python JsonMaker.py | ConvertFrom-Json

#Return to previous location
Pop-Location
```

Comment: By default `Start-Process` does not write anything into pipeline. With `-PassThru` it write `Process` object, but there are no option to write output stream into pipeline.

Comment: That actually sounds about right. Didn't have time to test. Removed. Thanks. :-) I didn't even add `-wait`